# Selenium .click() on link doesn't give the right address

Tags: django, selenium, testing, automated-tests, click

I'm testing a page.
I'm writing a functional test and I want to click on a link using Selenium 3.141 .
The link is working (if I click on it by myself).

The address should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists/addname/` but when selenium click on it go to `http://localhost:63286/lists/addname/lists/addname/` and ofcourse it doesn't find the page (63286 is a number always different but shouldn't be the problem, if I click on the link before it does (using time.sleep, for example) I go to the page `http://localhost:63286/lists/addname` and it works).

I'm not expert so maybe it's a trivial error and I don't know what code can be relevant, so tell me if you have to know more.

Edit: probabily is something related to load time /Edit

My `functional_tests.py`:

```
class NewVisitorTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_can_add_name_and_read_it_after(self):
        # Bob go to the homepage
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)

        # He notice the title in header is Home
        self.assertIn('Home', self.browser.title)
        # He finds and clicks the link on the sidebar for the addname page
        element = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Add Name')
        # element = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a') # this gives the same problem
        time.sleep(1)
        element.click()
```

In my `template.html` the link appear two time but that shouldn't be the problem:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'lists:addname' %}">{% trans "Add Name" %}</a>
</div>
[...]
<div class="sidebar">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'lists:addname' %}">{% trans "Add Name" %}</a>
</div>
```

My main `url.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('lists/', include('lists.urls')),
]
```

and my lists `url.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('addname/', views.addname, name='addname'),
]
```

My `views.py`:

```
def addname(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['item_text'])
        return redirect('lists/addname/')

    items = Item.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'addname.html', {'items': items})
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you confirm that the template does not contain any other link with that name ? what happen if you change for example `find_element_by_link_text('Add New Name')` and `{% trans "Add New Name" %}`  in the navbar ?

Comment: I confirm that I have only two "Add Name" and changing one of them doesn't change the result